# Prove or disprove $\exp(AB)=\exp(BA)$ where $A$ and $B$ are square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

> Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for 
>   exp(AB) = exp(BA) where $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

Notice that AB does not have to equal to BA.
What I can prove now is that det(exp(AB))=det(exp(BA)) since tr(AB)=tr(AB) implies exp(tr(AB))=exp(tr(BA)), which is sufficient that det(exp(AB)) = det(exp(BA)). Note that exp(tr(A))=det(exp(A)). This is a corollary of Jacobi's formula.

Thanks a lot!!

- [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)
- [On the Necessary and Sufficient Condition for a Set of Matrices to Commute and Some Further Linked Results](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2009/650970)

Comment: Of course a sufficient condition is that $A,B$ commute, that is $AB=BA$.  While it could happen even when $A,B$ do not commute, say $AB-BA$ is normal and all the eigenvalues of $AB-BA$ are integer multiples of $2\pi i$.

Comment: Thank you, but is there exist a necessary and sufficient condition? I understand it is a hard and potentially vague problem. Thank you again

Comment: If you don't like the answer of @GEdgar then you might only receive answers like <<a necessary and sufficient condition is $\exp(AB) = \exp(BA)$>>.

Comment: It's not true that $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(A) \text{tr}(B)$.  Whatever gave you that idea?

Comment: Sorry, it supposed to be tr(AB)=tr(BA). "det(exp(AB))=det(exp(BA))" should be true any way. Thanks

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a nonsingular matrix $X$.  It will have various logarithms (i.e. matrices whose exponential is $X$): let two of them be $Y$ and $Z$, and suppose $Y$ and $Z$ are similar.  Thus there is a 
nonsingular matrix $A$ such that $Z = A^{-1} Y A$.  Take $B = A^{-1} Y$, so
$Z = BA$ and $Y = AB$, and $\exp(AB) = \exp(BA)$.

Conversely, any case where $A$ is invertible will arise in this way, taking
$X = \exp(AB)$, $Y = AB$ and $Z = BA$.

Comment: What if A is not invertible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, finding a NSC valid for any $n$ is hopeless. Yet, the case $n=2$ is relatively simple.

Let $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $AB\not= BA$. It can be proved that

$e^{AB}=e^{BA}$ IFF

EDIT. EITHER i) $A$ or $B$ is invertible, for example $A$

$A$ is invertible and $B=A^{-1}P$ where $P$ is similar to $diag(u,u+2ki\pi)$ with $u\in\mathbb{C},k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

OR ii) $A$ and $B$ are singular

Up to a change of basis, $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0&b_{1,2}\\0&b_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}$, where

$a_{2,1}b_{1,2}+a_{2,2}b_{2,2}=2ki\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

$\textbf{Remark}$. In both cases, $e^{AB}$ is a scalar matrix.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. When $n\geq 3$, there are couples $(A,B)$ s.t. $e^{AB}=e^{BA},AB\not= BA$ and $e^{AB}$ is not diagonalizable.

$\textbf{Proof}$. Choose, for $n=3$,

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-2&0\\0&0&0\\0&12i\pi&6i\pi\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}-1/2&0&-1\\0&-1/2&0\\0&1&1/3\end{pmatrix}$.

We obtain $e^{AB}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.